# How do I disallow vertical scrolling in horizontal scroll group?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

This is my first project with SwiftUI so forgive my ignorance. Below I have a content view for which I created three scroll groups in a for-each loop to have the user scroll horizontally through the contents, like multiple playlists choosing in Spotify or Apple Music. But for whatever reason the first and third groups views I created allow you to scroll vertically as I show in the video below. **Is there any way I can explicitly disallow vertical scrolling in a HStack in SwiftUI (So if the user scrolls up or down the views in the stack don't move as well**, the one in the middle works perfect without allowing the user to scroll vertically just horizontally. Please note I don't have any more Swift Files and the app.swift just has it's default layout. The image below shows what the UI looks like if I drag up on the scroll group, the text below and the images go up or down depending on what the user is dragging, the one below doesn't have this issue but the one below that does

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Color(red: 0.16, green: 0.16, blue: 0.16).ignoresSafeArea()
            
            ScrollView {
                
                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                    
                    Image("SeeArt.")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 125, height: 50)
                        .padding(.leading, 15)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Image("Search Icon")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                }
                
                .padding()
                
                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                    
                    Text("Featured Artists")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .bold()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding()
                }
                
                VStack {
                    
                    HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 20) {
                        
                        Image("Andy Warhol Explore Page")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 175, height: 175)
                            .padding(.leading, 15)
                        
                        Image("Jean Michel Basquiat Explore Page")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 175, height: 175)
                            .padding(.trailing, 15)
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                        
                        .frame(height: 20)
                    
                    HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 20) {
                        
                        Image("Roy Lichtenstien Explore Page")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 175, height: 175)
                            .padding(.leading, 15)
                        
                        Image("Keith Haring Explore Page")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 175, height: 175)
                            .padding(.trailing, 15)
                    }
                }
                
                Text("Monthly Picks")
                    .font(.title2)
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                
                let monthlyPicksNames = ["Nakamura Keith Haring Collection", "Tate Modern", "The Broad Museum", "Museum für Moderne Kunst"]
                
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    
                    HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                        
                        ForEach(monthlyPicksNames.indices) { index in
                            
                            VStack {
                                
                                Image(monthlyPicksNames[index])
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                                    .padding(.leading, 15)
                                    .cornerRadius(5)
                                
                                Text(monthlyPicksNames[index])
                                    .bold()
                                    .font(.callout)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                    .padding(.leading, 15)
                                    .frame(width: 150)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Text("Quarterly Portfolio")
                    .font(.title2)
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                
                Image("Quaterly Portfolio 1")
                
                let museumNames = ["Whitney Museum of Art", "The Andy Warhol Museum", "Museum of Modern Art", "Nakamura Keith Haring Collection", "Tate Modern", "The Broad Museum", "Museum für Moderne Kunst", "MACBA"]
                
                let showMeSomething = ["Nakamura Keith Haring Collection", "Tate Modern", "The Broad Museum", "Museum für Moderne Kunst", "Whitney Museum of Art"]
                
                let handpickedStories = ["Nakamura Keith Haring Collection", "Tate Modern", "The Broad Museum", "Museum für Moderne Kunst", "Whitney Museum of Art"]
                
                let text = ["Exhibitions and Museums", "Show me Something", "Handpicked Stories"]
                
                ForEach(0..<3) { index in
                    
                    Text(text[index])
                        .font(.title2)
                        .bold()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    
                    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                            
                            if (index == 0) {
                                
                                ForEach(museumNames.indices) { index in
                                    
                                    VStack {
                                        
                                        Image(museumNames[index])
                                            .resizable()
                                            .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                                            .padding(.leading, 15)
                                        
                                        Text(museumNames[index])
                                            .bold()
                                            .font(.callout)
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                            .padding(.leading, 15)
                                            .frame(width: 150)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            
                            if (index == 1) {
                                
                                ForEach(showMeSomething.indices) { index in
                                    
                                    VStack {
                                        
                                        Image(showMeSomething[index])
                                            .resizable()
                                            .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                                            .padding(.leading, 15)
                                        
                                        Text(showMeSomething[index])
                                            .bold()
                                            .font(.callout)
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                            .padding(.leading, 15)
                                            .frame(width: 150)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            
                            if (index == 2) {
                                
                                ForEach(handpickedStories.indices) { index in
                                    
                                    VStack {
                                        
                                        Image(handpickedStories[index])
                                            .resizable()
                                            .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                                            .padding(.leading, 15)
                                        
                                        Text(handpickedStories[index])
                                            .bold()
                                            .font(.callout)
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                            .padding(.leading, 15)
                                            .frame(width: 150)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```